# Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com with CNAME and Openshift

Tags: redirect, dns, openshift

For eg. my domain is domain.com ( :D ) and my Openshift server has this url: domain-spiderman.rhcloud.com. (not true).

Now, I'm trying to configure the DNS zone so that:

> domain.com redirects to www.domain.com
>
> www.domain.com loads the website

The configuration I have already applied is this:

```
    domain.com. NS  dns111.ovh.net.     
    domain.com. NS  ns111.ovh.net.      
    domain.com. MX  1 mx1.ovh.net.      
    domain.com. MX  5 mx2.ovh.net.      
    domain.com. MX  100 mxb.ovh.net.        
    domain.com. CNAME   domain-spiderman.rhcloud.com.       
    www.domain.com. CNAME   domain.com.     
    domain.com. SPF "v=spf1 include:mx.ovh.com ~all"
```

The strange thing is that www.domain.com correctly loads the page, while domain.com has a loop towards domain.com and finally brake up.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I use this service (not endorsing anything, I don't know how safe it is or anything. I use it for my blog, so no stress):

http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect

Just point your naked domain A record to 174.129.25.170